# Flask redirect appends get%20/%20HTTP/1.1)uri on production server. Working fine locally

Tags: python, redirect, nginx, flask

I am trying to redirect all get requests to abc.example.com and send them to example.com. The following works on local:

```
 @app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
     def message_get():
         return redirect('https://example.com')
```

But on production server, it fails. Instead of getting redirected, the url looks like this:

> abc.example.comget%20/%20HTTP/1.1)uri

I observed that if I put in the whole url like this

> https://abc.example.com

it redirects properly. but abc.example.com or http://abc.example.com fails.

I have a flask app with gunicorn app server. Nginx is used as reverse proxy. Unable to determine which of them is causing the problem. Guessing something to do with my nginx configuration. But any pointers will help. thanks.

Nginx configuration:

```
    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name abc.example.com;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request)uri; }

    server{

        # SSL configuration

        server_name abc.example.com;
        listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
        include snippets/ssl-abc.example.com.conf;
        include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

        location / {
            include proxy_params;
            proxy_pass http://unix:/home/user1/apps/myapp/myapp.sock;
        }

        location ~ /.well-known {
                    allow all;
            } 
}
```

Comment: Please show your nginx configuration.

Comment: @DanielRoseman updated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your first server section; it should be:

```
return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
```

Comment: that was dumb! thanks for the quick reply. maybe I should delete this?